# Ограничение на количество символов после запятой в TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть ли опция у TextBox позволяющая напрямую ограничить количество знаков после запятой у его содержимого, не округляя постоянно значения, которые будут на него выводиться?

Т.е. например на загрузке формы мы "сказали", что 2 знака после запятой и забыли про него.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не надо ничего округлять, особенно если эти данные используются в дальнейших вычислениях, у дробных типов и так хватает проблем с представлением десятичных дробных чисел. `Decimal` проблем с представлением не имеет, он вроде как десятичный, но у него сильно ограничен диапазон значений (даже в сравнении с `float`) и он не используется математическими функциями, поэтому вместо округлений, появляются постоянные приведения.

Для вывода просто используйте форматированный вывод, например так:

```
double val = 01234.56789;
textBox1.Text = val.ToString("F2");//1234,57
```

Будет выведена целая часть целиком и ровно 2 знака после запятой. Осторожно с большими степенями, `1e100.ToString("F2")`, например, сформирует строку длиной 103 знака (100 на целую часть + разделитель дробной части + 2 знака дробной части). В случае больших степеней лучше подобрать другой формат, подробное описание возможных форматов [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) и [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx). Формат указывается обычной строкой, поэтому вы можете формировать ее динамически, например меняя точность вывода по необходимости.

Для ввода чисел, см. соседний ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Нет. TextBox в чистом виде не ориентирован ни на вывод чисел, и ни на вывод шаблонных представлений. Можно, конечно, добавить такую функциональность через наследование, или просто прицепить обработчик TextChanged.

Контрол ориентированный на шаблонные представление строк это MaskedTextBox, а для работы с числами -- NumericUpDown.

Comment: NumericUpDown работает с Decimal, это накладывает дополнительные требования по приведению результата к нужному типу перед использованием, плюс у него жестко задаются минимальное и максимальное значения, что в целом делает его удобным для финансовых приложений, но категорически неудобным для математических, где может требоваться ввод значений в экспоненциальном формате.

Answer (score 1):

Такая возможность есть, но это не опция у `TextBox`. Можно воспользоваться функцией `ToString(format)`. Пример:

```
double someValue = 0.1234567
myTextBox.Text = someValue.ToString("0.00"); // Результат: 0.12
// Или так: myTextBox.Text = $"{someValue:0.00}"; 
// Или так: myTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", someValue);
```

Здесь количество знаков после запятой определяется количеством нулей после точки в формате.

Таким образом вам придется в обработчике определенного события считывать значение из `TextBox`, пытаться преобразовать его в число с плавающей точкой, а потом осуществить его форматирование и запихнуть обратно.